# Simulator Works, Device Doesn't?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, openfeint

I have found out my issue on the device not working and simulator working. 
When i comment out this part, it works:

```
[OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"MYKEY" andSecret:@"MYSECRET" andDisplayName:@"LatinToGo" andSettings:settings andDelegates:[OFDelegatesContainer containerWithOpenFeintDelegate:self]];
```

So it looks like this:

```
//[OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"MYKEY" andSecret:@"MYSECRET" andDisplayName:@"LatinToGo" andSettings:settings andDelegates:[OFDelegatesContainer containerWithOpenFeintDelegate:self]];
```

it works perfectly when I comment out that part above, but when I click the open feint button, I get this error:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
```

I replace My key with my app Key in open feint and my secret with my app's secret code.

When I click the open feint button, it goes to a file and highlights this part in GREEN:

```
[inv invoke]; EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Then in my console when i Step into:

> 2012-04-28 08:53:12.076 BalloonsPop[500:707] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch 
>       Single stepping until exit from function +[OpenFeint(Private) launchDashboardWithDelegate:tabControllerName:andControllers:], 
>       which has no line number information. 
>       warning: Remote failure reply: E37

Any Suggestions to try? 
Thanks A lot!

Comment: It might work on your simulator because no network connection is available so OpenFeint probably aborts the operation.

Comment: I have tried this on many devices, all with Internet, the app loads up, but doesn't let me click any button, the app is causing it not to work because the openfeint code.

Comment: This happens because in your app delegate it does not give the view to another controller (the Root view Controller), so it means there is no default controller to fall back onto. I've had this error with three20 navigator (haven't defined the default action). So it probably means that there is no view returned from your openfeint call.

Comment: I have added a openfeint code to my app delegate.h and it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you do, but I would declare it like this:

```
OpenFeint *openfeint = [OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"MYKEY" 
    andSecret:@"MYSECRET" andDisplayName:@"LatinToGo" andSettings:settings
    andDelegates:[OFDelegatesContainer containerWithOpenFeintDelegate:self]];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: When i add this:                                                OpenFeint *openfeint = [OpenFeint initializeWithProductKey:@"MYKEY" andSecret:@"MYSECRET" andDisplayName:@"LatinToGo" andSettings:settings andDelegates:[OFDelegatesContainer containerWithOpenFeintDelegate:self]];                                           Then I get an error:                                                    Cannot initialize a variable of type 'OpenFeint *' with an value of type void'